# How do I stop GNU Freetalk from automatically filling in the buddy name?

Tags: linux, gnu

I'm using [GNU Freetalk](http://www.gnu.org/software/freetalk/) along with expect in order to send notifications to my phone – Freetalk has a `readline` interface, and I use `expect` to make a series of non interactive scripts that send information to another Jabber account.

I'd like to have these scripts end freetalk 'properly' – that is to say

```
user@domainname message one
user@domainname message two
/quit
```

which would print out

```
message one
message two
```

then quit.

However Freetalk 'helpfully' adds `user@domainame` automatically so I get

```
message one
message two
/quit
```

as the output. The expect script still ends, but there's a delay.

How would I stop Freetalk from adding in the 'buddy' address automatically?